# Trying to fit data to cotangens function using scipy.curve_fit

Tags: python, trigonometry, scipy-optimize

My data is quite similar to what the `arccos(x)` looks like so I think I'd succeed to make it. Using code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
        
x0 = [240, 320] 
y0 = [100, 99, 90, 60, 30, 10, 1, 0, 0] 

x = np.linspace(x0[0], x0[1], int((x0[1]-x0[0])/10+1))

def fun(x, a, b, c):
    return np.pi/2 - c*np.arctan(x*a + b)
        
p, c = curve_fit(f=fun, xdata=x, ydata=y0)
plt.plot(x, fun(x, *p))
```

I get almost straight line - not arccot shape and y domain is between 3.6 and 4.6, not in data range (0, 100).
I guess I'm missing something, but setting `bounds` didn't help. Maybe some additional parameters in the function should be populated or my own are wrong? Please give me some hint.

**EDIT**

Found an error:

```
def fun(x, a, b, c, d):
    return (np.pi/2 - np.arctan(x*a + c)) * b + d
```

The function has been detached and new parameters added as well.

Btw, I've fount those points of data fit make the `arccot` not behaving like typical function of this type, because the new `y` values are

```
array([102.37654247,  97.634854  ,  87.58354894,  62.42799136,
        27.36151993,  10.72835311,   3.75400887,   0.15012275,
        -2.0169414 ])
```

so there are some values over 100 and under 0, what is not good in domain I've set. Maybe there's some method to fit domain by using some other parameter or maybe I just overfitting?

**EDIT 2**

Found the best fit with values

```
x0 = np.array([200, 250, 260, 275, 290, 300, 350])
y0 = np.array([100, 97, 90, 50, 10, 3, 0])
```

which are slightly changed but the `arccot` is very stiff and its so symmetry sensitive, so there's a need to have some compromise.

Checking some values outside domain set by `x0` there are still offs:

```
fun(220, *p)
Out[448]: 99.71484816434646

fun(210, *p)
Out[449]: 100.25808335333575
```

but it's to be satisfied with some ifs.

Comment: What is your question after all the edits? For `fun(210, *p)`, I'm getting `96.35906849530042`. Can you summarize your question with code after the edits? also, summarize your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
def fun(x, a, b, c, d):
    return (np.pi/2 - np.arctan(x*a + c)) * b + d
```

The function was wrongly built. The issues with overfitting such function with 4 parameters which has only one entry for shape change cause that I never fit it to all points, even they seems to be on the "target". It's possible to remove `c` and `d` and get better fit. Or just change function to polynomial for example.